# Java: Statically check that two pair of classes implement a certain function

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

Let's say I have two abstract classes `A1` and `A2`. Is there a way to ensure that every combination of (`C1` extends `A1`, `C2` extends `A2`) has a certain `operation()` defined? I want to make sure the code does not compile if there's even one combination of two children that does not provide an implementation for `operation()`.

Comment: There is not enough information here.  How are A1 and A2 related (if at all)? What do you mean by _"every combination of (`C1` extends `A1`, `C2` extends `A2`) "_?  Please be more explicit and provide a real code sample of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Let's say as an example there's one an abstract class `IO` and abstract class `Question`. I want to implement a function `validate()` for every possible combination of children and verify that there's such implementation at compile time. For instance, if there's two `Question` children: `MultipleChoice` and `Essay`, and one IO: `Console`, I want to make sure there's `validate()` for (`Essay`, `Console`) and (`MultipleChoice`, `Console`).

Comment: Edit your question instead of clarifying in comments. And what is `(Essay, Console)`? That isn't Java.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... Is there a way to ensure that every combination of (`C1` extends `A1`, `C2` extends `A2`) has a certain `operation()` defined? ..."*

Mark the *operation* method as *abstract*, or use an *[interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)*.

> *"... I want to make sure the code does not compile if there's even one combination of two children that does not provide an implementation for `operation()`. ..."*

This will cause any *sub-class* of *A1* or *A2* to require an implementation of, *operation*.

```java
abstract class A {
    abstract void operation();
}

abstract class A1 extends A { }

abstract class A2 extends A { }

class C1 extends A1 {
    @Override
    public void operation() {

    }
}

class C2 extends A2 {
    @Override
    public void operation() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a HasOperation interface

```
interface HasOperation {
    void operation();
}
```

Have A1 and A2 implement the HasOperation interface but not the operation method

```
abstract class A1 implements HasOperation {
}
```

etc

Every concrete (not abstract) subclass of A1 and A2 will need to implement the operation method